# scrape the data-title and data-video-id on single page

Tags: scripting, imacros, scrape

I want to scrape the data-title and data-video-id but i don't know how to write the script with imacros

[The Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAUBw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TR ATTR=CLASS:pl-video<SP>yt-uix-tile* EXTRACT=HTM
SET data-title EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/data-title=\"(.*?)\"/)[1]")
SET data-video-id EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/data-video-id=\"(.*?)\"/)[1]")
SET !EXTRACT {{data-title}}[EXTRACT]{{data-video-id}}
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```